# Redirect loop with Secure Browsing when using Facebook app?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I've developed a Facebook application using the `C# SDK`, and since I've entered a Secure Tab URL and Secure Canvas URL, people who have `Secure Browsing` turned on in their Facebook settings just experience an infinite redirect loop. It directs to the site my app is hosted on, then back, then back, then back and so on and so on.

I'm creating a new `CanvasAuthorizer` instance, then setting the `ReturnUrlPath` to the URL of the tab page, then I'm calling `.Authorize()`.

Without secure browsing, this all works fine, but with secure browsing, it just redirects over and over again.

I've tried searching for an answer, but I've not had much luck so far.

**EDIT:** Investigating a bit further, the .Authorize() call is failing. It's returning false. I really have absolutely no idea why that is.

**EDIT 2:** Just to clarify, authorization fails when Secure Browsing is on, but works fine when it is turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much head-scratching, I discovered the reason for the failure was that SSL wasn't set up correctly on the website where I was hosting the application. This was causing authentication to fail, because it was redirecting itself to a non-HTTPS site.